# Why can't lock value of User input?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a speadsheet

exist data from row 2-> 4:

If a user open file, sheet will lock if row exist data.

User input row 5 & 6, close file

But user open file again, file only lock row 2-> 4, row 5 & 6 is not lock.

This is my code of `function onOpen(e)`

```
function onOpen(e){
    var oSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    for(var i=2;i<10;i++)
          {
            if(oSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() !="")
            {

              var protection = oSheet.getRange(i, 2).protect().setDescription('protectedrange');
              var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
              protection.addEditor(me);
              protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
              if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
                protection.setDomainEdit(false);
              }
            }
          }
}
```

Why can't lock value of User input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple triggers like onOpen could do certain things when they the active user is the owner of  the spreadsheet but cant' do the same things when the active user is an editor.

The certain things are those that require authorization like protecting a range.

Instead of using a simple trigger use an installable trigger.

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers